# How do I set date to datepicker in xcode?

Tags: xcode, datepicker

I have a datepicker named `updateDate`, i want it to set the date to a given date (`NSDate *dateToGet`). how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setDate:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDatePicker/setDate%3aanimated%3a) is what you're looking for.

```
[updateDate setDate:dateToGet animated:YES];
```